# Linq replace values until first X value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list:

```
var l = new List<int?>{0,0,0,0,0,0,4,5,6,3,0,0,2,3};
```

I want to replace all starting "n" zeros values with `null` until find first `value != 0` and break.

I tried to use `Select`:

```
var l2 = l.Select((x, i) => i == 0 || l[i - 1] == 0 ? (int?)null : x)
```

Actual Result:

```
{null,null,null,null,null,null,null,5,6,3,0,null,null,3}
```

Expected Result:

```
{null,null,null,null,null,null,4,5,6,3,0,0,2,3}
```

[MRE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0z7Vxy):

```
public static void Main()
{
    var l = new List<int?>{0,0,0,0,0,0,4,5,6,3,0,0,2,3};
    var l2 = l.Select((x, i) => i == 0 || l[i - 1] == 0 ? (int?)null : x);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", l2));
}
```

Note that this question is a rework of https://stackoverflow.com/q/60304342/1248177. I think that the question had some legs so here we go.

Comment: Can you confirm that you want to change the existing list, not create a new one?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I am fine with creating another list. (Oh I see what you said later)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution I came up with. It's not quite as elegant, but it works and uses `Select`:

```
var l = new List<int?> { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 3, 0, 0, 2, 3 };
var firstIndex = l.FindIndex(x => x != 0);
var m = l.Select((item, index) => firstIndex == -1 || index < firstIndex ? null : item);
```

This code will also replace all elements with null, if every element is zero.

Here is an example of it working in both cases: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wJMBfx

Comment: I forgot about `FindIndex`. This solution uses the same logic as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60305036/1248177), but rely on a List's builtin. We are less generic though. This is a good solution :)

Comment: Ah, nice edit. I realise that checking if `item` is 0 is kinda pointless when we have `firstIndex`.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this in Linq is to build a `ReplaceWhile` function:

- Count how many element match your condition.
- While you didnt reach the position replace with the subsitute.

Code:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ReplaceWhile<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, T substitute)
{
    var zerosLength = source.TakeWhile(predicate).Count();
    return source.Select((x, i) => i >= zerosLength ? x : substitute);
}
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JAHbya)

Answer (score 1):

If we're creating an extension method I think I would prefer it this way:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ReplaceWhile<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, T subsitute)
{
    var matching = true;
    foreach(var item in source)
        yield return !matching ? item : (matching = predicate(item)) ? subsitute : item;
}
```

Iterates every item exactly once, no need to first iterate to find an index or do a count etc.

Edit: [Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JgP0YI)

Comment: A working O(n) solution? Nice. Not fan of the assignation in the ternary though. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without auxiliary variables:

```
var l = new List<int?>{0,0,0,0,0,0,4,5,6,3,0,0,2,3};
l = l.TakeWhile(x => x==0).Select(x => (int?)null).Concat(l.SkipWhile(x => x==0)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60305036/1248177), but here is the another one:

- Count how many element match your condition.
- Prepend a collection of substituteto your source after skipping the right number of elements.

Code:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ReplaceWhile<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, T substitute)
{
    var zerosLength = source.TakeWhile(predicate).Count();
    return Enumerable.Repeat(substitute, zerosLength).Concat(source.Skip(zerosLength));
}
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1S8bSO)